# What is crtbegin.o and crtbegin_dynamic.o?

Tags: android, c, linux, gcc, android-ndk

When debugging a link error (`undefined reference to _dso_handle`) using the Android x86 toolchain, I noticed it's statically linking `crtbegin_dynamic.o`. What is the purpose of this file? There is another similar `crtbegin.o` in the toolchain install directory that contains the missing symbol (_dso_handle). What is the difference between crtbegin.o and crtbegin_dynamic.o?

Comment: Logicor provided this answer. I'm going to reproduce it as a comment since its probably going away: *"Here is a more detailed explanation on this: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Initialization.html"*.

Comment: Related: [Difference between crtbegin.o variants?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22160888/608639). It does not look like a dup (otherwise, I would cast the first vote on my question).

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I think they relate to dynamic libraries (shared objects) and executables, but not quite sure. Hope this provides you a lead.

Answer (score 11):

C++ has global constructors and destructors. crtbegin.o and crtend.o deal with calling those constructors and destructors. The variants of crtbegin.o such as crtbeginS.o do the same thing for other types of executables such as static executables and shared libraries.