# What does start address mean for dynamic library?

Tags: dynamic, shared-libraries

I just discovered that shared libraries also have got `start address`:

```
objdump -f /usr/lib/libTH.so

/usr/lib/libTH.so:     file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000150:
HAS_SYMS, DYNAMIC, D_PAGED
start address 0x0000000000026e60
```

It is clear what it does mean for executable, but what is it for shared objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as in a program, the start address (a.k.a *entry point address*) of a shared library is simply
the start address of the `.text` segment, containing all the executable
code.

Here's a toy shared library too illustrate:

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    printf(__func__);
}
```

Compile and link:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -c foo.c
$ gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o -Wl,-Map=libfoo.map
```

Let's see its start address:

```
$ objdump -f libfoo.so 

libfoo.so:     file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000150:
HAS_SYMS, DYNAMIC, D_PAGED
start address 0x0000000000000530
```

We requested a linker map file, `libfoo.map`, when we linked the SO. Here's
the `.text` section from that map file:

```
.text           0x0000000000000530       0xf2
 *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
 *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
 *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
 *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
 *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
 .text          0x0000000000000530        0x0 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
 .text          0x0000000000000530       0xda /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbeginS.o
 .text          0x000000000000060a       0x18 foo.o
                0x000000000000060a                foo
 .text          0x0000000000000622        0x0 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtendS.o
 .text          0x0000000000000622        0x0 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
 *(.gnu.warning)
```

As per `objdump`, it starts at address 0x530. It is 0xf2 bytes long. From the five
files that the linker loaded:

```
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbeginS.o
 foo.o
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtendS.o
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

The input `.text` section of `crti.o` was empty and contributed 0 bytes.
Then `crtbeginS.o` contributed 0xda bytes, but no symbols. Then `foo.o`
contributed 0x18 bytes at address 0x60a, including the symbol `foo`. Then
`crtendS.o` and `crtn.o` each contributed 0 bytes. 0xda + 0x18 = 0xf2. (The
files that had empty `.text` sections will have contributed something to
other output sections, not shown).

So, at the start address of the library we find the code `crtbeginS.o`,
which is C runtime initialization code  - the shared library version -
for finding global constructor functions (i.e. constructors of any C++
global objects or C functions qualified
with `__attribute((constructor))`). See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22160888/1362568).

In summary, the start address of the shared library enters that library's contribution
to the runtime initialization of the program with which it is dynamically linked.